# merge two transparent images without lose transparency

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics

I have two PNG images with transparent background. 
I need to merge them to one image without losing transparent background.

I used this code

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(firstImage.size);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSaveGState(context);

  CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, firstImage.size.height);
  CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, firstImage.size.width,firstImage.size.height);
  // draw white background to preserve color of transparent pixels
  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDarken);
  [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
  CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

 CGContextSaveGState(context);
 CGContextRestoreGState(context);

  // draw original image
  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDarken);
  CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, firstImage.CGImage);

  // tint image (loosing alpha) - the luminosity of the original image is preserved
  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDarken); 
 //CGContextSetAlpha(context, .85);
  [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:secondImage] setFill];
 CGContextFillRect(context, rect);


 CGContextSaveGState(context);
 CGContextRestoreGState(context);

 // mask by alpha values of original image
 CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationIn);
 CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, firstImage.CGImage);

 // image drawing code here
 CGContextRestoreGState(context);
 UIImage *coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 return coloredImage;
```

but it return one image with white background.

Any idea why, please?

Comment: what's with the `CGContextSaveGState` & `CGContextRestoreGState` functions being adjacent? You need to save the state before making changes to the state, and then restore after.

Comment: i am new in CGContext & UIGraphics, i found this code here, but doesn't work. But thanks for reply

Comment: You seem to have copied and merged random code. Why are you using `kCGBlendModeDarken` and `kCGBlendModeDarken`. Why are you setting and restoring graphic states? Don't just copy code you found. You need to know what it does. This problem isn't hard. It only seems hard because you're doing somewhat random stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both of your images have transparency, then drawing them both with the normal blend-mode won't in any way 'lose' the transparency.

You should just be able to draw one on top of the other:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(firstImage.size); // Assumes the first image is the same size as the second image.
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, firstImage.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, firstImage.CGImage);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, secondImage.CGImage);

UIImage *coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return coloredImage;
```

You also don't need to save and restore the graphics state of the context (at least outside of *all* the drawing), unless you are going to reuse the context.

Comment: no worries! I highly recommend you have a good read of the Quartz 2D docs if you want to do further work in Core Graphics: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-TPXREF101. Ray Wenderlich also has some nice tutorials: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/core-graphics

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand very well the problem but let's try...

Try to set the view where the images will be with **setOpaque** like the example bellow...

```
[self.thatView setOpaque:NO]
```

Hope that helps.